# Defining the smallest subset of $\Pi$ that's closed under $f$ and contains $a$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I need to model family relationships so I want to define the set of a person's direct descendants. I try to use recursion to construct such a set but I'm not sure if my definition is just circular.

My definition is as follows:

> Let $\Pi$ be the set of all people. For $x \in \Pi$, their father is given by $F(x): \Pi \to \Pi$. Then, for any male, $\alpha \in \Pi$, the set of their direct descendants is given by
>
> $$\mathcal F_{\alpha} = \{x \in \Pi: F(x) \in \mathcal F_{\alpha} \wedge \alpha \in \mathcal F_{\alpha} \}$$

I'm also considering

> $$\mathcal F_{\alpha} = \{x \in \Pi: F(x) \in \mathcal F_{\alpha}\} \cup \{\alpha\}$$

Are these definitions valid? Are they equivalent? Do they accomplish my goal?

Let me know what you guys think. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you replace $\mathcal{F}_\alpha$ with $\Pi$ in the first equation. The left hand side is $\Pi$ and the right hand side is also $\Pi$ because $F(x) \in \Pi$ does not impose any restriction and $\alpha \in \Pi$ is already true. You need some sort of minimal solution property.

Comment: I think you want the smallest subset of $\Pi$ that 's closed under the application of $f$ and contains $a$.

Comment: I see what you guys are saying. How would I include the minimal solution property to achieve the smallest subset? Could I define a set, $P$, containing all possible $F_{a}$ and select its smallest element? Do I need to define a set of all $F_{a}$ or is there some way I can stipulate that $F_{a}$ be as small as possible?

Comment: You are talking about ancestors, not descendants. Furthermore, you’re talking about indirect ancestors not direct ones. Your father, grandfather, great grandfather, etc. are ancestors not descendants; you are their descendent — the direct descendent of your father, ibut ndirect of your great^*-grandfathers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally be wary of using the object being defined in a definition of that object. Really, such an expression isn't really a definition at all. Rather, it should be thought of as a kind of "logical equation" which - *hopefully!!* - has a unique solution, and **that more complicated expression** ("the unique solution of ---") is a valid definition ... *once* a correct proof of unique-solution-ness has been exhibited.

Neither of your candidates works in this respect. For example, besides the intended interpretation, the choice $X=\Pi$ also satisfies the equation $$X=\{x\in \Pi: \mathcal{F}(x)\in X\wedge x\in X\}.$$

By contrast, the logical equation $$Z=\{z: z\in Z\rightarrow z\not\in Z\},$$ despite looking very weird at first glance, **does** have exactly one solution (namely $Z=\emptyset$); as yet another contrasting example, the equation $$A=\{x: x\not\in A\}$$ has no solutions at all.

---

OK, so what do you do?

Well, one option is to **build on what you've already done**. When you have an intuitively-compelling logical equation with too many solutions, one possible fix is to see if the intended solution is in some way "distinguished." In particular, you may look for the **intersection of all solutions**, e.g. $$Y=\bigcap_{X=\{x\in \Pi:\mathcal{F}(x)\in X\wedge x\in X\}} X.$$ Even if - as in your case - the equation you have in mind has too many solutions, this object **is** uniquely defined, and moreover is (as long as your equation has a certain form, which yours does) also a solution to your equation - the *smallest* solution, in a precise sense.

Another option is to **work with sequences**. Think about buildng the relation "$b$ is a descendant of $a$" in stages, with stage $n$ being the relation "$b$ is a descendant by $\le n$ generations of $a$." You get a sequence of relations $(R_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, and the relation you want is the union of this sequence of relations: $b$ is a descendant of $a$ iff $bR_ia$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N}$. This is a "from-below" construction, as opposed to the "from-above" construction in the previous paragraph; each approach has its place, and understanding why they give the same thing is a fundamental exercise!